# Using LINQ in an MVC project, how can I orderby a joined table's value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two classes that I join together:

**Item**

(a bunch of properties)

(Foreign Key) int Category

**Category**

(Primary Key) int ID (this is referenced in Item)

string Name

Using LINQ in my MVC 5 project, I need to get and sort by the Name value from the category table using the ID in the Item table.  With the code below, it is sorting in the order of the integer (1,2,3,4) instead of by the Name property in the Category table.  How can I sort by the category table?

**Controller code:**

```
var items = from s in db.Items 
            join c in db.Categories on s.Category equals c.ID
            select s;

switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Category_Desc":
                //This is where it is selecting the integer ID instead of the string Name
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.Category);
                break;
            default:
                items = items.OrderBy(s => s.Category);
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Category` property of your `Item` class is an int, so it is going to order those as it would any other integer. Right now your join serves no purpose since you are selecting only the items at the end of your query. Select an anonymous object instead which contains both the category and item, then you will have access to the properties of your `Category` class and can sort by the name and select only the `Item`.

```
var query= from s in db.Items 
        join c in db.Categories on s.Category equals c.ID
        select new { item = s, cat = c };
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "Category_Desc":
        //This is where it is selecting the integer ID instead of the string Name
        items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.cat.Name);
        break;
    default:
        items = items.OrderBy(s => s.cat.Name);
        break;
}
var items = query.Select(s => s.item);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing!  I liked Anu's answer too, but yours has similar syntax to what I am already using. Also a note: I had to capitalize the S on select in query.select and change it to query.Select.

Comment: @sjohn285 I have edited the answer and capitalized the S. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

You could try following.

```
var result = db.Items
            .Join(db.Categories,i=> i.Category, c=>c.Id,(i,c)=>new {item =i, category=c})
            .OrderBy(x=>x.category.Name).Select(x=>x.item);
```

The crux is creating an interim structure, which comprises of Category.Name.